# Bsurface error in 2.8

Tags: topology, error, annotation

I'm trying Blender's Bsurface add on for topology which works great up until I cross my guidelines and I don't know why.

I been watching a tutorial by Darrin Lile and whenever he crosses his guidelines, he doesn't have an issues. As far as I can tell, he didn't really tweak anything to do so either. Here's a screenshot below.

[image]